# Seeking 110v plug that is easy to grip

Tags: electrical, connectors

The 110 v electrical plug on my vacuum cleaner started to fray. I put on a replacement plug but I have a little difficulty pulling the plug out of the wall.

I would like to replace the plug with one that either has a handle or is big enough to really grip and with a shape that is easy to grip, so it is easy to pull out of the wall.

Do such replacement plugs exist and, if so, what are they called?

Comment: you could drill a hole in the center and attach a zip-tie to grab...

Answer (score 3):

[Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-125-Volt-Grounding-Plug-Yellow-515PV/301305057?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-2_WIRING_DEVICES%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000034239053%7C58700003946878363%7C92700031954447748&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxO_3nbzv2wIVkx2BCh2ASQVrEAQYBSABEgKKMvD_BwE&dclid=CLnRw6-879sCFUlkwQod8VgLWA) is one of many sources for a larger plug that can be attached to existing wiring.

[image: large plug]

As noted in the photo, this is a three conductor type plug. Most vacuum cleaners are only two conductor. You can ignore the third connection if your machine is that type.

I did not search specifically for this larger plug in two conductor form for that reason. You may find that the store you select will have that type on the shelf.

These plugs are quite easy to grip. I've repaired two extension cords with these connectors and it's been working quite well.

Comment: I found this one which is about 3.5 inches long, but has no real handle: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001M58SUG/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1  The little indents on the sides do not provide a good grip.  I prefer one with a shape that you can really grasp.

Comment: Every "easy grip" plug I've found is directed to the camping world and 220v high amperage applications, unfortunately.

Comment: So is your vacuum 2 prong or 3 prong?